# Document AI Contract Processor with Human-In-The-Loop: Processor type not found for getting predefined fields for validation criteria: 48

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-console, cloud-document-ai

The Human-in-the-Loop configuration Wizard for the "Contract Processor" in US region has failed while applying the configuration made from the Console, with the following error in the Console error logs.
[image]

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 5,
      "message": "Processor type not found for getting predefined fields for validation criteria: 48"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "XXX"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "requestAttributes": {},
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "documentai.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.documentai.uiv1beta3.DocumentProcessorService.UpdateHumanReviewConfig",
    "resourceName": "projects/XXX/locations/us/processors/3e85a4841d13ce5/humanReviewConfig"
  },
  "insertId": "dlpi8nb10",
  "resource": {
    "type": "audited_resource",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "aptsonicxx",
      "service": "documentai.googleapis.com",
      "method": "google.cloud.documentai.uiv1beta3.DocumentProcessorService.UpdateHumanReviewConfig"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-01-16T18:31:21.160785363Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/XXX/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "projects/XXX/locations/us/operations/5578187298605838878",
    "producer": "documentai.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-01-16T18:31:22.140730942Z"
}
```

Since then, I am stuck, unable to modify or to amend the configuration. "Manage Configuration" leads to the threshold and results folder settings, with the confirmation button or cancel not having any effect.

Have I missed something?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. Has this worked before? Have you been able to enable Human-in-the-Loop for any processor? Have you been able to do this for a Contract Processor before?

Comment: Hello @HoltSkinner , I have been able to enable HITL for a Form Processor. I tried creating another Contract Processor, same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this, I reproduced the issue in my own project. I'm going to report this as a product issue to the development team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HoltSkinner as mentioned, this is a **confirmed bug/issue** and has already been reported internally to the development team.

You may follow this [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/265713284) for this specific issue and click on **+1** to bring more attention to the issue.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Comment: This error is shown because the Contract Processor does not currently support HITL; a product change is in progress to remove this option from the UI.